# Accessing an element within a list of Json objects using handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.java

```
"guests": [
    {
      "guestname": "john smith",
      "is_active": false,
      "guestheight": "175cm",
      "guestprofile": "https://www.example.com"
    },
    {
      "guestname": "david smart",
      "is_active": false,
      "guestheight": "175cm"
    }
  ]
```

I would like to check if guestprofile exist. Given that I currently have a variable holding the index of the list we are trying to access here, namely `itemIndex`. So basically I'm trying to query `if guests[itemIndex]["guestprofile"]` in handlebars.js context.

If I make a direct reference like

```
{{#if guests.0.guestprofile}}
  //do something
{{/if}}
```

its working fine. However, if I replace 0 with itemIndex like below, everything broke...

```
{{#if guests.itemIndex.guestprofile}}
  //do something
{{/if}}
```

Currently I have also tried

```
{{#if (lookup guests itemIndex).guestprofile}}
  //do something
{{/if}}
```

```
{{#if guests[itemIndex].guestprofile }}
  //do something
{{/if}}
```

None of them actually worked. Please help, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You were *so* close with your `lookup` attempt.

The issue is that Handlebars does not allow you to chain a key onto a lookup subexpression as you are doing with `(lookup guests itemIndex).guestprofile`. It just doesn't resolve dynamic variables that way, which is the same reason why [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) has to be used instead of `guests.itemIndex.guestprofile`.

The part you missed is that you actually need *two* lookups - one to get the element of `guests` at `itemIndex` and the second to get the `guestprofile` of that element.

Your template needs to become:

```
{{#if (lookup (lookup guests itemIndex) 'guestprofile')}}
    do something
{{/if}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9sLqc2yb/) for your reference.